# How can I make a two dimensional structure(dictionary inside a dictionary) using python and pymongo to store in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I will be getting below data frequently,

```
item_1 = { "ip" : "66.70.175.192", "domain" : null, "date_downloaded" : "2017:08:23 12:25:05", "scanned_date_with_port" : [ { "scanned_date" : "2017:08:22 04:00:03", "port" : 25 }, { "scanned_date" : "2017:08:22 04:00:03", "port" : 110 } ], "ports" : [ 25, 110 ] }
```

How can I save data into pymongo in the below structure:

```
{"ip_1" : {"port" : [scanned_date_1, scanned_date_2]}, {"port_2" : [scanned_date_1, scanned_date_2]  }, "domain_name" : ["domain"] }
{"ip_2" : {"port" : [scanned_date_1, scanned_date_2]}, {"port_2" : [scanned_date_1, scanned_date_2]  }, "domain_name" : ["domain"] }
```

Whenever new IP comes If already exist need to append, else add new. If port is already in one Ip append the port with scanned_date else add that port and scanned_date.

How can I do it efficiently? There will be a massive data to be looped.

```
for item in all_items:
```

Each "item" will have the above structure of item_1.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to maybe change your data structure and unify the way how are treated new IPs and IPs already in the DB in a way that you just ask for a given IP and a port and you get the structure, either partially populated or empty and you will always append the new data - either to existing list or to an empty list. You will something like a factory for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $push update operator to append to an array. Here's a complete example:

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

collection = db.collection
collection.delete_many({})
collection.insert_many([
    {"_id": "ip_1", "port": [1, 2], "port_2": [1, 2], "domain_name": "domain"},
    {"_id": "ip_2", "port": [1, 2], "port_2": [1, 2], "domain_name": "domain"},
])

# A new request comes in with address "ip_2", port "port_2", timestamp "3".
collection.update_one({
    "_id": "ip_2",
}, {
    "$push": {"port_2": 3}
})

import pprint
pprint.pprint(collection.find_one("ip_2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the soulution.

```
        bulkop = self.coll_historical_data.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

        for rs in resultset:
            ip = rs["ip"]
            scanned_date_with_port = rs["scanned_date_with_port"]
            domain = rs["domain"]
            for data in scanned_date_with_port:
                scanned_date = data["scanned_date"]
                port = data["port"]
                # insert if not found, else update
                retval = bulkop.find({"ip" : ip}).upsert().update({"$push" : {str(port) : scanned_date }, "$addToSet" : {"domain" : domain}} )

        retval = bulkop.execute()
```